# how do I getting data from different table & from different column should make a same column as result?

Tags: mysql

```
id  customer    
1   deva
2   prakash


customer    num 
deva        1
rani        2
virat       7


id
1
2
7
```

I need 3'rd table structure and result form other two table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ever read about `Union`?

Answer (score 0):

`Union` should give you the expected result:

```
select id from table1
Union 
select num from table2
```